# Prometheus google cloud monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, prometheus

We are Moving from datadog to prometheus,
Datadog have google cloud metrics, for example:
gcp.gcp.instance.is_running 
gcp.gcp.project.quota.networks.limit
and more .. (all metrics starting with gcp)

i want to have those google cloud metrics using prometheus - 
is there an exporter to get them?couldn't find anything .